# Would an inertia electric motor propel a spacecraft in zero gravity?

Tags: gravity, space, propulsion

There's an interesting mechanic that is used by self balancing proof of concept robots where they have a wheel on two axis and when the stock robot starts to pivot and fall over, it spins the wheel moving it back into position, then stops spinning the wheel waiting for the next correction.

You can do the same thing if you are sitting on a skateboard, if you can lean forward and rapidly thrust your bottom half forward, moving yourself forward, then lean forward again and do it again. You're slow movement to change position without moving the vehicle, and using a fast movement to generate a lot of energy in a short time.

Will this work in space? Or would the slow movement push the spaceship back, making it so no matters how hard you dangle in space you won't be able to generate any movement?

Answer (score 2):

Internal movements in spacecraft cannot move its center of mass. A spacecraft could be rotated about its center of mass by applying different forces to a flywheel or gyroscope, but this would only affect its orientation or spin, it would not cause spatial translation of the center of mass.

Comment: uh, what if you move the center of mass, and take turns doing opposite inertial movements with the center of mass being in different locations.

Answer (score 1):

Your first paragraph has nothing to do with you actual question. You are mistaking effects there. A Segway robot moves forwards and backwards by falling forward or backwards just like you do when walking. It initiates this from standstill by moving its base out from under its center of gravity. You do this by doing the reverse: moving your COG out from over your feet.

At standstill works to keep its base under its center of gravity so it doesn't fall in either direction just like you do when standing, except you move your COG to do that whereas the robot moves its base.

Once falling, both you and the robot move your base so it stays a fixed distance from your COG so you don't actually topple over and hit the ground.

**EDIT**: It occurs to me you might be referring to a reaction wheel balancing robot like Cubli which doesn't actually perform any translational motion, and not a two-wheeled Segway robot. That would make more sense.

---

But to answer your inertialess movement question, no. That relies on the fact static friction is higher than dynamic friction between solid objects. So no. You can do the same spinning an office chair. A really bad squeaky one one will be easier than a good one that spins smoothly.

And it doesn't work in a boat floating in a pool either where there is no static friction because the dynamic friction (i.e. drag) once you get moving increases with speed.